# how to disable First Person Controller in ursina

Tags: python, ursina

i making pause menu in ursina and i dont know how to disable mouse always on top
and disable First Person Controller in ursina, a tryed:

```
player.FirstPersonController.disable()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it that way

```
player.enabled = False
```

Comment: this code no function

Comment: Can you share more code? For example how you initialized the First Person Controller.

Comment: global menu
                menu = False
                global player
                quit.visible = False
                settingss.visible = False
                Play.visible = False
                player.visible = True
                top.visible = False
                FirstPersonController.visible = True
                logo.visible = False
                logo_text.visible = False
                player = FirstPersonController()
                gamescreen.visible = True
loadingscreen.visible = False
tree.visible = True
global game
game = True